# Tensorflow: how to replace one operation in the graph by another?

Tags: tensorflow

Currently I have following issue, I used `Placeholder` to create Input to my network, it is start node, operation with index zero:

```
placeholder_operation = net.graph.get_operations()[0]
```

But now I want to replace it with trainable `Variable` input, to minimize loss changing input(adversarial samples).

I can do it rebuilding my graph entirely through my algorithm, replacing first `Placeholder` operation with `Variable`. But is there more elegant way to do it?

Also, in general, if I have only graph of operations(no algorithm that constructed this graph), can I replace random node in this graph by some other operation? I.E. deleting and installing new nodes in any place in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

[tf.placeholder_with_default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default) is a pretty nifty option. You can use it to switch out any Tensors, be they Variables, Placeholders or Constants.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

trainable_variable = tf.Variable(3.)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
my_placeholder = tf.placeholder_with_default(trainable_variable, trainable_variable.shape)

b = tf.constant(2.)
c = my_placeholder * b


# Use this when you want to use `trainable_variable`
sess.run(c) # 6.0
# Use this when you want to use `my_placeholder`
sess.run(c, {my_placeholder: 5.}) # 10.0
```